# How to type correct answer in the last try without showing the game over text

Tags: java

I am a beginner and as you can see I made a simple Java game.

The user has 5 tries to guess a number between 1 and 20.
If the user wins a congratulations message will show.
If the user didn't succeed a game over message will pop up.

#### Issue

When the user enters the right answer on the 5th try both congratulations and game over messages will pop up.

#### Code

```java
package org.meicode.Loops;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("Enter your name please ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        System.out.println("Type 1 to start the game");

        int yes = scanner.nextInt();
        while (yes != 1) {
            System.out.println("Type 1 to start the game");
            yes = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Guess the number in my mind,It is between 1 and 20 and you got 5 tries");
        int timestried = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
        while (timestried < 5) {
            timestried++;
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int answer = scanner.nextInt();

            if (x == answer) {
                System.out.println("Well done, you did it");
            } else if (x > answer) {
                System.out.println("Try again,hint:the value is bigger than what you typed");
            } else if (x < answer) {
                System.out.println("Try again,hint:the value is smaller than what you typed");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Game over, the number was " + x);
    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt. I have added some comments in the code to help you.

Note that I have changed some of the file names to, so you may need to change them back for it to run, or just copy the main code section:

```
package com.misc;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Welcome");
            System.out.println("Enter your name please ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = scanner.next();
        
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        
            System.out.println("Type 1 to start the game");
        
            int yes = scanner.nextInt();
            //We initialize the answer variable here to use it later on.
            int answer = 0;
        
            while (yes != 1) {
        
                System.out.println("Type 1 to start the game");
        
                yes = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        
            System.out.println("Guess the number in my mind,It is between 1 and 20 and you got 5 tries");
            int timestried = 0;
        
            Random random = new Random();
            int x = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
        
            //Print out the randomly generated number so we can test it. We answer wrong 4 times then put in the right answer to see if the message is fixed.
            System.out.println("Testing: the answer is " + x);
            while (timestried < 5) {
                timestried++;
        
                Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                answer = scanner.nextInt();
        
                if (x == answer) {
                    System.out.println("Well done, you did it");
        
                } else if (x > answer) {
        
                    System.out.println("Try again,hint:the value is bigger than what you typed");
                } else if (x < answer) {
        
                    System.out.println("Try again,hint:the value is smaller than what you typed");
                }
        
            }
            //This is the conditional that uses the answer variable we declared earlier above to avoid printing out the Game Over message in a success scenario.
            if (x != answer) {
                System.out.println("Game over, the number was " + x);
            }
        
    }

}
```

Here is proof that it works. I made the program print out the real answer, answered wrong 4 times and correctly the 5th time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple fix

There are 2 things I would add to your code to achieve the desired behavior:

1. **break or exit the loop** on correct answer
2. **set a flag** signaling the question was solved to later build the message upon it

#### Basics: How to break loops and why

You can achieve this by two ways:

1. *break* the loop when the user typed the correct answer
2. *add an exit-condition* to the loop
3. *return* from the whole method prematurely
4. *throw* an exception that can either be caught outside or will also exit the method

I will explain (1) and (2) here in this answer (3) in a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70570353/5730279).

#### (1) Breaking the loop

The loop shall continue until:

- the maximum number of tries has been reached
- the correct answer was given

Use a `break;` statement to break the loop if correct answer:

```
if (x == answer) {
  System.out.println("Well done, you did it");
  break;
}
```

Note: contrary a `continue;` will skip further loop-body and jump to the next iteration.

#### (2) add a flag signaling premature exit (e.g. correct answer)

You can add a flag that is set to `true` if the user types the correct answer:

```
boolean userHasAnsweredCorrect = false;
while (timesTried < 5) {   // here the flag can be added instead breaking
  if (x == answer) {
    System.out.println("Well done, you did it");
    userHasAnsweredCorrect = true;
    break;
  }
}
// omitted some lines .. then at the end
if (userHasAnsweredCorrect) {
   System.out.println("You beat the game!")
} else {
   System.out.println("Game over, the number was " + x);
}
```

See how you define the flag before the loop, set it inside the loop (together with a `break;`) and then test on the flag after the loop.

#### Combined: set flag and add exit-condition

```
boolean userHasAnsweredCorrect = false;
while (timesTried < 5 && !userHasAnsweredCorrect) {   // here the  break happens instead
  if (x == answer) {
    System.out.println("Well done, you did it");
    userHasAnsweredCorrect = true;
    // break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find 2 more simpler ways of breaking the loop [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70570353/5730279), here follows the 3rd way:

Put the whole game into a method like `startGame()` and exit from that. Either exit after loop with max-tries has finished or inside the loop (prematurely) if answered guess was correct.

#### (3) Exiting the loop and method using `return`

That premature method-exit can be achieved by inserting a `return;` inside the loop.

```java
public void startGame() {
    // rest of preparation

    // starting the game-loop
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxTries; i++) {  // for-i is indexed and safer (no infinite-loop)
        // read input

        // score or evaluate answer against x
        if (x == answer) {
            System.out.println("Well done, you did it");
            return;  // exit the method, not reaching "game-over" after the loop
        }
        // continue the iteration
    }
    // game-over (if not previously exited because of victory)
}
```

To have an exit-condition for the `for` loop, define `int maxTries = 5` either as local variable, class field or constant.